Can you taste-test multiple brands of matzah, even if your custom is not to eat matzah before Passover begins?
There is a common practice not to eat matzah preceding Pesach, either on erev Pesach or in the weeks before. The reason for this is so that matzah will be eaten on the Seder night with gusto.
Faced with a choice of different matzah brands, at different price points, Shlomo has acquired a sampling of matzah brands — broken pieces from people he knows. He wants to conduct a taste test, to see whether certain brands taste like cardboard or if they are tasty. Then, he will go to the store and buy more for himself and his family. Finally, he'll be able to eat the matzah on the Seder night with gusto.
Is this permitted, because of the ultimate aim?  Or is it prohibited, because it goes against his established custom?

I would say it is ok as it supports the purpose of the minhag. In any event compare to https://shulchanarukh.alhatorah.org/Full/Orach_Chayyim/567.1#e0n6

For the record, refraining from masah on 'erebh Pesah is not just minhag (custom): אכילת מצה בערב פסח. The Rambam goes so far as to say that one is liable for makath marduth (lashes for rebelliousness) if one does consume it.

+1 interesting,  thanks. I'd read the Talmudic phrasing otherwise, but good to know how various rishonim take it.

If it’s really just a taste, one that doesn’t require a bracha and is permitted on a fast day, then it shouldn’t be a problem. The reason is to EAT the matza for the first time on Pesach and this isn’t called eating. As an aside, I don’t know his source, but my Rav said less than a kzayis is not a problem

Based on Yechaveh Daat 3:26, Chazon Ovadia Pesach Page 201, Rav Ovadia brings many Rishonim who say that Shlomo can rely on those opinions who hold that one can eat matzah that was not לשם מצוה before Pesach and taste which ever matzah he chooses. Practically I think Shlomo can do this by going to any matzah factory and asking them if they have any matzah that was made not לשם מצוה (and I'll add, any matzah that they made which passed the 18 minute mark). I know this doesnt really answer the question, but its a solution :)

Nice. I wonder about 18 minute since it is really hiluch mil and some hold that would be 22 minutes.

Right, but you get the point, if they mess up and have matzah baked more than 22 minutes it would work as well

indeed, but I'd add the points from here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/90601/becoming-chametz-at-18-mins Namely, after 18 or 22, it is just possibly chametz, so we should concerned, look for signs. And that is after 18 minutes of letting it sit without working the dough, otherwise, without chumras, even hours and hours and it would be non-chametz and valid matzah.
